# Hard disk not showing up while installing windows 7

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Hard disk is showing up in bios while setting up boot priority, But not showing up when computer ask for the partition to install windows.

I tried resetting bios but no luck

Then i thought DISKPART would work, when i run the command LIST DISK it shows up the flash drive only.

Comment: Confirm that the disks SMART stats indicate that it is healthy. I'd try reading them from an ubuntu live CD since you don't have an OS installed. hopefully it will be able to see the disk.

Comment: Sorry i had to edit my question.

Comment: You can slipstream the Sata drivers (mass storage) into your W7 installation media using [Driver Packs](http://driverpacks.net/)

Comment: The same thing could happen if this is a GPT disk and you are using a non UEFI motherboard. Try initializing it as MBR. You should also scan it with the manufacturer diagnostics tool or at least test it in a different system.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to add the SATA drivers. Download the drivers for your hard drive controller to a USB drive. Then boot into the install routine and navigate to the screen that is supposed to show all of your disks. Click on the Load Drivers button at the bottom of the screen and navigate to where you stored them on your USB drive. Once it loads the drivers it should find your disk.

*** Note: You need to extract the drivers from the executable first. The folder that you point the installer to must have the *.inf and *.sys files.

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: I'll update the status here.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install windows on a laptop last week and i had the same issue. Non of the partitions would show up. What i did was boot into Ubuntu and format the disks. If you're 100% sure it isn't a hardware fault drivers and formatting will be your only option.